# Displaying a Category on a Wordpress Page

Tags: categories, shortcode

I have a game.php file and all main categories are displayed there with a shortcode. output results by category. Question. You don’t need to output in category.php so that I don’t throw it on category.php ... I only need to insert these shortcode that you see below not into the game.php `([main-category])` or category.php files themselves `([child-category])`, but in the page. If you insert a shortcode in the game’s page, the main category, that is, everything you need to insert `[child-category]`, if I am transferred to category.php

`([main-category])`
`([child-category])`

front-page.php

```
    public function get_main_category(){

$arg_cat = array(
    'orderby'      => 'name',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'   => 0,
    'exclude'      => '',
    'include'      => '',
    'taxonomy'     => 'category',
    'parent'       => 0,
);
//global $wppb_login;
//if (is_user_logged_in() || isset($wppb_login->ID)){?>




</div>
    <div class="main"><?php
        $all_categories = get_categories($arg_cat);
            $category_link_array = array();
            foreach( $all_categories as $single_cat ){
                $category_link_array[] = '<div class="hexagon" ><div class="wrap"><a href="' . get_category_link($single_cat->term_id) . '">' . $single_cat->name . '</a></div></div>';
            }
            echo implode('', $category_link_array);
        ?>  
    </div> 
    <?php }
```

category.php

```
    public function drag_drop_category(){



    function is_subcategory($catid){
        $currentcat = get_category($catid);
        if ($currentcat->parent) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    ?>

    <body>
    <?php
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $sub_category = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));

    $cat_id = $sub_category->cat_ID;

        if (is_subcategory($sub_category)) {
            ?>
            <div class='parent'>;
                <div class="headline">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
                </div>
                <div class='parent_c'>;
                    <?php
                    if ($category->category_parent == '0') {
                        wp_list_categories(array(
                            'hide_empty' => 0,
                            'child_of' => $category->term_id,
                            'title_li' => __(''),
                        ));
                    }
                    ?> 
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        } else {
            $params = array(
                'cat' => $category->term_id,
                'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query($params);
            if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        ?>  
                    <a style=" top:10%;" href="#" onclick="display_hide('#question');return false;">Padomi <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
                    <?php
                    echo "<div class='container-tips'>";
                        echo "<div class='container-question' id='question' style=\"display: none; width: 40%; \">";
                        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
                            the_title();
                            the_content();
                        endwhile;
                    echo " </div>";
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
            echo "</div>";
            $query = new WP_Query(array('cat' => $category->term_id,'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),));
            ?>
            <form id="cardsForm" action="category.php" name="Form" method="post">
                <div class="main">
                    <div class='container-cards' id='drag'>
                        <div class="container-drag">
                            <?php
                            $i = 1;
                            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                                $query->the_post();
                            ?>  

                                <div class="hexagon-cards-drag"  data-type="cards<?php echo $i ?>">
                                    <div class="hexagon-cards-drag-outline"   id="drag<?php echo $i ?>">
                                        <div class="wrap" ><?php echo  get_the_title(); the_content();echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $query-> ID ); ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            <?php $i++; } ?>
                            <?php wp_reset_postdata();
                            echo '<br >';
                            ?> <h1 class="category_card-title"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
                                    <div class="hexagon-cards-drag"  data-type="cards-text-1" >
                                        <div class="hexagon-cards-drag-outline"  id="drag-area1">
                                            <div class="wrap"> <textarea name="comment" id='my_textarea' cols="40" rows="3"></textarea></p></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 

                                    <div class="hexagon-cards-drag"  data-type="cards-text-2" >
                                        <div class="hexagon-cards-drag-outline"   id="drag-area2">
                                            <div class="wrap"> <textarea name="comment" id='my_textarea' cols="40" rows="3"></textarea></p></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>    

                                    <div class="hexagon-cards-drag"  data-type="cards-text-3" >
                                        <div class="hexagon-cards-drag-outline"  id="drag-area3">
                                            <div class="wrap"> <textarea name="comment" id='my_textarea' cols="40" rows="3"></textarea></p></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <?php } ?>


</body>

<?php 

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not quite sure, if I understand what your question is and what is it that you're trying to do. Could you perhaps rephrase your question, please?

Comment: I have a game.php file and a created Game page. In it I insert a shortcode that displays the main categories. When I click on a category, it automatically throws me to category.php and the subcategories are already displayed there and by clicking on the subcategory the content is displayed to me. Is it possible that these subcategories are not displayed on category.php, but in another file, for example, '' i-create-all-my-category.php "

Comment: so on a subcategory page you want to hide the navigation, that is part of your `category.php`, correct?

Comment: @nilsons Thank you, now I'm starting to understand what you mean. Could you post your `category.php` code, so that the we can give a more detailed answer to your particular case.

Comment: I added the code, please look

Comment: @h0nk31 
I want not to be thrown at me on category.php when I click on the main category. I need to create pages and insert shortcodes to display the main categories and subcategories. I can get the main ones anywhere by inserting a shortcode. But subcategories are displayed only on category.php and I can’t create a page in the admin panel to display them, as I always throw on category.php